# Exclude One URL From Python URL Masking

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have never written a python script in my life, but I have a question that  can hopefully be solved pretty quickly...

I'm using Google App Engine and [Dropbprox](http://code.google.com/p/dropbprox/). The script uses a custom domain to point to your public DropBox folder for better DropBox URLs. I'd like to be able to redirect users to my main site (jacob.bearce.me) if they visit my dropbox url (dl.bearce.me).

The problems that I'm having:

- I've never used GAE or Python before, so I have no idea where to even begin

  Putting a index.html file in my GAE project didn't fix it (I was hoping it'd just default to that if there was no filename specified, like it would on a normal site, but no cigar.)

Just a simple redirect if a users visits the main URL is all I'm after, nothing fancy.

My Python file: http://dl.bearce.me/mirror.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `main.py` that issues a redirect for all requests, using the Python 2.5 runtime environment:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('http://jacob.bearce.me/')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainHandler)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here's the `app.yaml` file you need to route URLs to this handler:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

(Replace `myapp` with your actual app ID.)

For more information about creating and uploading an App Engine app in Python, see the [Getting Started tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/introduction.html).

Comment: (Can't actually test till I get home...) So will that only work if someone visits the main `dl.bearce.me site`, and not a specific file? I basically need it to redirect users if they visit `dl.bearce.me` but work with my mirror.pl script if they visit `dl.bearce.me/folder/file.ext`

Comment: Assuming this app is hosted on `dl.bearce.me`, as written this redirects all paths to the root of `jason.bearce.me`.  But you can extend the example easily to preserve the path.  The path is in the variable `self.request.path_info`, which you can add to the redirect's URL string.

Comment: Wow, I didn't understand this until I took a look at it over a month later. Thanks, I'll implement this when I get home tonight...